# how can i get an object name when it is created in java?

Tags: java, objectname

when an object is created how can i get the name of that object ??

for example let's consider a class Book:

```
public class Book {
  private String name;
  private int pages;

  public Book(String name, int pages) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pages = pages;
  }

  }
// now i create an object of this class
Book book = new Book("Java",100);
```

i want to get the name of the object created that is "book", is there any way to get it  ?
i tried the toString(), function and it does not work it prints something like this: @3d4eac69

Comment: What do you mean by the "name" of the object? The `name` property? The name of the class? The name of the variable you've assigned it to?

Comment: This seems impossible.

Comment: Objects don't have names. Variables do, but objects don't. Understand that the same object referenced by the book variable can be referenced by a whole host of other variables. Which variable represents its name? Or an object can be part of an array or ArrayList and thus not be part of a "named" variable. So again, objects have no names.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate as this and similar questions have been asked many many times. I'm not sure that we need yet one more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you mean the `name` property, you can't with your code as written. You'd need to either make `name` public, or provide a public getter for it
2. If you mean the name of the class, it would be

   ```
   book.getClass().getName()
   ```
3. If you mean the name of the variable you've assigned it to (`book`), you can't, that isn't information available at runtime (outside of a debug build and debugger introspection).

Comment: Nice answer, good explanation why it is impossible to get (point 3) +1

Comment: i meant the third option, so it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the getter method in Book class. Would be like:

```
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

And then you would call:

```
book.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
book.getClass().getName();
```

Every object in Java has `getClass()` method:
[getClass() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass())
And every `Class` object has its name:
[getName() documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName())

Comment: You need object name, don't class name.

Comment: Yes, sorry, so it is impossible to get @AndrewTobilko